# cakephp validates() not working in REST api

Tags: php, validation, rest, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

i am trying to validate data before insert,update and delete into database table using validates() in cakephp.
one thing that has to be noticed that i am doing this with REST api.
i want that, when i call an api for insert,update,delete before it perform the task it must be validate the data.
like i want to insert an email address if input is not an email then it should give me an error message,but it always comes in if condition which is wrong.
my code is given below -

controller:-WebserviceController.php

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
 class WebserviceController extends AppController {
 public $components = array('RequestHandler','Api','Paginator','CurrencyConverter.CurrencyConverter');
 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
 }
 public function add()
 {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->User->set($this->request->data);
    if ($this->User->validates()) {
        $this->set(array(
        'result' => array(
            'status' => true,
            'msg' => __("validation are working")
        ),
        '_serialize' => array('result'),
    ));
    } else {
        $this->set(array(
        'result' => array(
            'status' => false,
            'msg' => __("invalid email input")
        ),
        '_serialize' => array('result'),
    ));

    }
 }
```

model:-UserModel.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class UserModel extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
    'email' => 'email'
    );
}
```

I tried so hard but no luck. I am stuck, please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($this->request->data);`?

Comment: This is the ouput but this is not the problem.problem is that validates() not working.                                                                                       <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <b>array</b>
    <i>(size=1)</i>
  'email' 
    <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>'abcxyz'</font>
    <i>(length=6)</i>
</pre>

Comment: You should name your model `User` not `UserModel` and you are loading `User` in your controller, there is your problem.

Comment: I have changed the model name from UserModel to User but no luck.

Comment: The proper way of debugging validation errors is through [$Model::validationErrors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html#validating-data-from-the-controller)

Comment: Also rename the file `UserModel.php` to `User.php`